# Transforming a subview of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, core-animation

I am trying to reproduce an effect like the iOS 7 app switcher where I can scroll between smaller, transformed views. My current obstacle is getting the contentOffset

In order to do this, I have added a scrollView to my view, and sized it to the bounds of the view. I then create a container view that holds on to all the 'cards' -- it is this container view to which I apply the transform.

Anyway, the issue I am having is with adjusting **where** a particular card appears after it has the transform applied -- right now, I am unable to adjust the contentOffset during the transform in a manner that is smooth.

Anyway, code would help! Here it is:

```
NSInteger idx = selectedCardIndex;

if (TransformApplied)
{        
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.container setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
        [self.container setFrame:CGRectOffset(self.container.frame, (1-ScaleFactor)/2 * NumCards * ScreenWidth, 0)];
        [self.scrollView setContentSize:self.container.frame.size];
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(ScreenWidth * idx, 0) animated:NO];

        [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        TransformApplied = NO;
    }];
}
else
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.container setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(ScaleFactor, ScaleFactor)];
        [self.container setFrame:CGRectOffset(self.container.frame, (-1)*((1-ScaleFactor)/2) * NumCards * ScreenWidth, 0)];
        [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(ScreenWidth * ScaleFactor * NumCards, ScreenHeight * ScaleFactor)];
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(ScaleFactor * ScreenWidth * idx, 0) animated:NO];


        [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:NO];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        TransformApplied = YES;
    }];
}
```

**More**
I am noticing that everything is smooth when applying the identity transform, but not when applying the smaller transform, I get a weird 'jump' in the frame before the animation.

If i comment out the content offset adjustment in the scale transform (the bottom block) then everything runs smoothly, but the contentOffset is wrong after the scale transform.

Lastly, calling setContentOffset:animated: results in a wonky animation so that is a no-go.

Any help greatly appreciated!!!!

**UPDATE**

I've looked in to anchor point/ position properties on CALayer, and I've got the animation effects working perfectly with this:

```
NSInteger idx = selectedCardIndex;

if (TransformApplied)
{
    [UIView dd_AnimateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.container setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(ScreenWidth * idx, 0) animated:NO];

        [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        TransformApplied = NO;
    }];
}
else
{
    CGPoint anchor      = CGPointMake((idx * ScreenWidth + ScreenWidth/2)/CGRectGetWidth(self.container.frame), 0.5f);
    [self.container.layer setAnchorPoint:anchor];
    CGPoint position    = CGPointMake((anchor.x) * self.container.frame.size.width, self.container.layer.position.y);
    [self.container.layer setPosition:position];

    [UIView dd_AnimateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.container setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(ScaleFactor, ScaleFactor)];

        [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:NO];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        TransformApplied = YES;
    }];
}
```

However, now i've got to figure out a way to get rid of all the extra space in the scrollview without allowing the position of the container to change....

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue a long time ago about the position of a view. After a long research, I ended up with the `UIView` documentation. It says about `transform` and `frame` properties of a `UIView` with a warning:

> **Warning**:
>   *If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.
>   Changing the frame rectangle automatically redisplays the receiver without invoking the drawRect: method. If you want the drawRect: method invoked when the frame rectangle changes, set the contentMode property to UIViewContentModeRedraw.
>   Changes to this property can be animated. However, if the transform property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead.*

So, the basic idea is that, you shouldn't rely on or change `frame` when your view's `transform` contains a non-identity transform.

And the more important idea, always give a chance to the official documentation before looking elsewhere.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Right. So changing the frame of self.container might not be the best way to handle the incorrect location of the view in the scrollview. However, another approach might be to embed this container itself in another container, and offset the frame of that accordingly. I am having a little difficulty with the math right now unfortunately :(

Comment: Maybe you should animate your `container` using `CAKeyframeAnimation`s, with `position` and `transform.scale` keypaths.